# How to add a separator line after specific item in NSTableView (Cocoa/OS X)

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm building a program that gets weather forecasts from the Met Office using their DataPoint API. This gives me forecast data for five days into the future, with eight forecast points (every three hours) for every day. It displays them in an NSTableView, which currently looks like this:

```
27/3/2016 at 0:00     6°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 3:00     4°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 6:00     4°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 9:00     7°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 12:00    8°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 15:00    8°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 18:00    8°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 21:00    6°C  ...
28/3/2016 at 0:00     6°C  ...
28/3/2016 at 3:00     8°C  ...
28/3/2016 at 6:00     8°C  ...
...
```

However, when viewing five days of this all at once, it is very hard to read it day by day (determine where each day starts and ends without looking at the dates) and this is not user friendly in the slightest. So, I want to add a separator line (or separator cell, depending on how it can be done) after the last forecast step of each day, to separate the string of data out into easily recognisable days. I want it to look like this:

```
27/3/2016 at 0:00     6°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 3:00     4°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 6:00     4°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 9:00     7°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 12:00    8°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 15:00    8°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 18:00    8°C  ...
27/3/2016 at 21:00    6°C  ...
-------------------------------
28/3/2016 at 0:00     6°C  ...
28/3/2016 at 3:00     8°C  ...
28/3/2016 at 6:00     8°C  ...
...
```

What is the best way that I can do this (in a single NSTableView, put separators at select points in the dataset)? Thanks

Comment: How about an `NSOutlineView`?

Comment: @CodeDifferent isn't that for showing collapsible trees of data? I just want to put a line under specific cells in an NSTableView's data

Comment: How are you populating the table? If you are using a data source delegate, just return a line of dashes in `tableView(_ ,
objectValueForTableColumn:, row:)`

Comment: You can add a table cell view in the tableview and add horizontal line as subview of cell view. Populate this cell whenever you need a separator.